# How do you prevent a duplicate from being added to the list by subject name? And how do you find an item in a list by name?

Tags: python, list

How do you prevent a duplicate from being added to the list by subject name? And how do you find an item in a letter by name?

```
shopping_list = []

product = (name, price , quantity, shop_name)

if name not in product:
    shopping_list.append(product)
```

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What is a "subject name"? What are the "items" you mentioned? You might want to look at [dictionaries](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp).

Comment: Where are you setting the value of 'name'? Also the product variable never changes so the if will always trigger.
And why are you NOT using a dictionary here?

Comment: What letter are you talking about in "find an item in a letter"?

Comment: Find an item in a list by name, not a letter. I apologize for the error in the question.
I am beginner at python, it seemed to me that it was not necessary to use a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to check if an item is already in your shopping list. A modified version of this can be used to find items by name. I would recommend adding a unique ID for each shopping item because names could potentially overlap.

```
def checkInShoppingList(shopping_list, product):
    in_list = False
    for item in shopping_list:
        print(item)
        if item[0] == product[0]:      #Checks each item in list and see if name is a match
            print('Item is in list')
            in_list = True
            break                       #So it won't iterate through rest of shopping list
    if not in_list:
        shopping_list.append(product)   #Add item to list
    return shopping_list


shopping_list = [('item1','3.50', '2', 'shop1')]
product = ('item2', '3' , '1', 'shop1')   
shopping_list = checkInShoppingList(shopping_list, product)
product = ('item2', '3' , '1', 'shop1')   
newList = checkInShoppingList(shopping_list, product)           #Test to add same item again
print('New Shopping list:', newList)
```

[Online Python Compiler](https://onlinegdb.com/HJibptUAV)

I would also recommend making each product in the array a dictionary

Comment: Well formatted answer, but you would be better off putting the shopping list in a `dict` instead of scanning the entire list to see if you have the product every time you want to look.